# Rename file by removing last n characters

Tags: shell, unix

I want to rename files by removing the last N characters

For example I want to rename these files by removing the last 7 characters

From:

```
file.txt.123456
```

To:

```
file.txt
```

Is this doable in a single command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove a fixed number of characters using

```
mv "$file" "${file%???????}"  # 7 question marks to match 7 characters
```

This will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

To remove the last extension (which may be more or less than 7 characters), use

```
mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
```

To trim everything after a given extension, you can try

```
EXT=csv
mv "$file" "${file%.$EXT.*}".$EXT
```

which actually removes `.$EXT` and everything after, but then reattaches `.$EXT`.

Comment: What if I only want the file extension to be in .csv?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `mv "$file" "${file%.csv}"` would strip `.csv` from the file name, but not another extension (which would be a no-op, since you would simply rename the file to itself).

Comment: Let's say I have a file name `file.12323.csv.txt.13123` and I want it to be `file.12323.csv`

Comment: Good question :) I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using bash?

```
file="file.txt.123456"
mv $file ${file::(-7)}
```

Comment: This has worked for me numerous times before. Now all of a sudden I am getting the error: -bash: (-7): substring expression < 0. Any ideas??

Comment: Your string is too short, and you're asking bash to remove more characters than it has. :)

Comment: But my file names are extremely long? Similar to this: ```T591_Name_Anothername_L200.fasta.new.new```. I'm using this in a loop as I've done a million times in the past. ```for file in *.new; do; mv $file ${file::(-7)}; done.```I'm baffled.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to Adam's, but without bashisms (since it was tagged shell not bash).

```
remove_n(){
  echo ${2:0:$((${#2}-$1))}
}

remove_n 8 file.txt.1234567
#remove last 8 characters from 2nd argument
#for filenames in variables use
mv "$VAR" `remove_n 8 "$VAR"`
```

Comment: `${foo:offset:length}` is the same bashism used by Adam.

Comment: it is also supported by other shells though, for instance busybox ash, whereas the other method isn't

Comment: I don't follow. The only difference I see is that Adam uses a negative length, while you compute an explicit positive length.

Comment: ::() is different than :${start}:${length} and `()` is not supported, but $((integer ops)) are nor is a negative value for substring manipulation, so start from position :0 (the zero is not required, but left in place to show intent) and go the length of the string ${#varname} minus the amount we need to take off which has to be done in $(()) outside of bash.  I use busybox ash a lot, so the differences stick out.

Comment: OK, so it appears that `ash` and `bash` have two slightly different implementations of the same non-standard construct. Good to know.

Comment: @chepner - no, bash has additional implementations.  both ways should work in bash, but this way will work in bash _AND_ other shells (maybe not dash or posix sh, but most others)

Answer (score 3):

To do so for every file in directory you can use this.

As in first answer 7 question marks to match 7 characters

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file%???????}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by a single command, at least you can do it with some pipes:

```
mv file.txt.123456 $(ls file.txt.123456 | rev | cut -c8- | rev)
```

Looking at your example, I'm wondering if a pattern like "removing characters from the last dot to the end" would be a better fit.